# I can't generate post view in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I'm following the steps on this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywxIElNbcj4&index=12&list=PLMTiAh6qhda1-MVtXe1vs_99CghP5pd01

When i click on the indidivual posts, the view is not loaded and i get the following error:

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined method Post::getPostById()
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\application\controllers\article.php
>
> Line Number: 11
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once"

Why can't it recognize `getPostById()`? Is there any library missing?

This is my repository with the files:

https://github.com/ashcrimson/aplicacion

Comment: You don't follow [convention](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/styleguide.html#file-naming) with capitilized controllers, libraries, models and classes in general. read whole page to avoid similar issues.

Comment: It tells you what error is there is no getPostById() function

Comment: Your question doesn't help much. Post the code you have in article.php as well as the view

Comment: Also your filenames wrong follow this way https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your article.php weren't able to locate Post::getPostById($id) because you didn't include the Post Model or define it in your autoloader so that article.php able to find it. 
In your controller, load the Post Model where youre getPostById() exist.

```
class Article extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        /* Load model in the constructor. 
      * Include the folder name if you have, for example applications/model/admin/post_model.php , 
      * call it as admin/Post_model (where Post_model is your model class name)
    */

     $this->load->model('Post_model','',TRUE);

    }
    public function post ($id ='')
    {
        /*
         your code here
         */      
         //Retrieve data 
            $post = $this->Post_model->getPostById($id)->row(); 
    }
}
```

Quoting [Code Igniter User Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/)

It has a very clear step by step tutorial for beginners.

Comment: This actually fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: It would be great if you can mark this as useful. ^_^  . Happy Coding!